# Android ViewPager has stale views

Tags: android-viewpager

I'm having a problem with a ViewPager where, upon app startup, the pager has views with stale information, despite a refresh of the list that underlies the associated PagerAdapter. The final step of that refresh is calling the adapter's notifyDataSetChanged method, but the fragments don't end up getting refreshed, at least initially. They do get refreshed whenever swiping the pager causes the framework to call the adapter's getItem method. Myi mplementation of getItem instantiates a new fragment (using the current data from the underlying list of items).

One thing I notice is that the adapter's getItemPosition method is never called in response to the notifyDataSetChanged call. Several posts on SO have indicated that returning POSITION_NONE is the way to indicate that the fragment should be reloaded. But getItemPosition is never invoked, so that has no effect.

One mystery is where are the old Fragments coming from. I think the system has some way of magically re-instantiating them, but I'm having a hard time understanding the whole fragment lifecycle. In any event, it's not what I want, at least not without a way of telling the adapter (or maybe the pager itself?) "please refresh everything". I thought that calling
notifyDataSetChanged was the way to do this, but it ain't working. It's as if PagerAdapter has no way of informing the Pager that the data is now different, and that it should ask for a refresh.

The question, I suppose, is: if the data underlying a pager has changed, how do you inform it that the data is stale and it should request a new fragment (or maybe update the existing one)?